# Exit code "1" on diff command despite getting output

Tags: diff

```
user@mbp$ diff --suppress-common-lines -y file1.txt file2.txt
```

Some output

```
user@mbp$ echo $? 

1 

user@mbp$
```

I'm curious why it throws exit code 1 rather 0 if its giving me what I need?

I realize this is more of a shell in general question rather than ubuntu.

Comment: `Exit status is 0 if inputs are the same, 1 if different, 2 if trouble.` - from `man diff`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a quick reading of the diff man pages showed me that the exit codes are different than what I was thinking.

Exit code 1 = differences were found.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I also faced the same issue and exit code when there is a difference is 1. In my scenario, I was using this in a script where I would be outputting the difference, which will be easy if in case I need to troubleshoot when there is a failure.

So to avoid the script failing due to the above error, I used the command in the below format from failing,
diff file1.tst file2.tst || true

In this way, the command will get executed and since it has been ORed with true the exit code will be 0 and the script will continue without exiting.

Hope it helps!!!